# Write all axioms and properties for the Boolean algebra of sets P(S) (power set)

Tags: boolean-algebra, axioms

Write all axioms and properties for the Boolean algebra of sets:

$S = set$

$(P(S), \cap$$, ∪ , complement; ∅, S)$

I know the axioms of Boolean algebra but I am not sure how to translate that to a power set

$(B, + ,·,' ; 0,1 )$

1) $+,·$ are closed operations in $B$:

$x + y ∈ B$

$x · y ∈ B, ∀ x, y ∈ B$

2) identity elements:

$x + 0 = 0 + x = x$

$x ·1 = 1·x = x, ∀ x ∈ B$

3) +,· are commutative:

$x + y = y + x$

$x·y = y·x, ∀ x, y ∈ B$

4) $+,·$ are distributive one relative to the other one:

$(x + y)·z = x·z + y·z$

$(x·y) + z = (x + z)(y + z), ∀ x, y, z ∈ B$

5) $∀ x ∈ B, ∃ x' ∈ B$, the complement of $x$, such that:

$x + x' = 1 and x x' = 0$

6) There are at least two elements in$ B$:
$0 ≠ 1$

Comment: what is the question exactly? also, do Boolean algebras need to be lattices? because if so then they also need to be closed under meets and joins (I think), which correspond to infimums and supremums, i.e. the union of two sets and the intersection of two sets. In other words here, I believe your addition should be set union and your multiplication should be set intersection.